# some Users can see other users information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

some users of my site contact me and said that they have a problem to see their information. the problem is that they see information of other users ! 
i developed my site by asp.net mvc 3 and asp.net membership. when i logon by that username and password everything is ok. i think something happened like ISP cash or network cash for them ! because other users hasn't any problem. i check my code and no problem find !

Answer (score 0):

ISP cache or network cache can not cause this problem. you should search for this problem in your code. also authentication method is not in charge of this problem.

the problem maybe because of session or cookie expire. when a session expires, your app may look for a default data (for example form other user roles) and present it. so should look for such security holes in your application.

another problem maybe because of caching problem in your code or asp.net cache ! caching users data and show it to other users!

Answer (score 0):

I once had something like this happen on an ASP.NET page. Turned out the problem was that I had caching enabled on one of the pages and so the user could see the information on a previous user.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that you are caching results server-side and not varying the cached information by the user.  Either you need to vary the caching by the parameter that is related to the user or by the user themselves (using VaryByCustom).

Example:

```
[AuthorizeByUser( Roles = "Admin" )]
[OutputCache( Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam="*", Duration = 500 )]
public ActionResult Profile( int id )
{
   ...
}
```

Varying by all parameters here means that each value of the id parameter will have a different cache entry.  Here we assume that id is related (perhaps is) the user's id so each user will have a different cached entry.  Note your security (the AuthorizeByUserAttribute) would also need to be set up so that it won't serve up cached results to unauthorized users.  Here I'm assuming an implementation derived from AuthorizeAttribute which verifies that the user is in the "Admin" role or has a user id related to the id in the method signature.  See my blog post on custom authorization for ideas on how to do this: http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2011/03/revisiting-custom-authorization-in.html.

Comment: but just 2 or 3 of users see this problem not all of theme ! 
is it related to server cache  ?
how can i check the resolution after make changes to my application to assure?

Comment: @user - caching issues are very dependent on situation.  To make sure that it' a caching issue, I would turn caching off at the controller level.  Comment out any OutputCache attributes and a apply `[OutputCache( Location = OutputCacheLocation.None )]` to each controller in your app.   If this solves the problem, then selectively reapply your caching attributes making sure to vary per user in a test environment using different user ids, but the same request parameters, that you're not getting cached responses.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem when we brought in the source code from another digital agency. We took their codebase and added more features to it. Testing went fine on both dev and staging and we went ahead to publish it.

As soon as the site went live, we had a lot of users complaining that they were seeing other users’ information as soon as they logged in. We couldn’t replicate it because it happened intermittently.

We thought it could be static method. Replaced all of them by instantiating an object and call that method, the problem was still there.

We thought it was Singleton pattern. We removed them but the problem was still there.

It took us weeks to figure out the culprit. The issue was the load balancing feature set up by the previous digital agency. It was working fine on their two load balancing servers. The problem started as we were hosting on one server. As soon as we turned it off, the problem went away. However, the damage was done. We lost a lot of customers as they didn’t trust our system anymore.

It happened eight years ago but I still have nightmares about that issue from time to time.